# Parsing WSDL with Axis2?

Tags: parsing, wsdl, apache-axis

How can I parse WSDL using Axis2?

Answer (score 1):

WSDL is just special XML and can be parsed by any XML parser. You can parse it using most Web browsers. If you have WSDL file and want to generate `.java` client source skeleton then use `wsdl2java` that is part of axis2. Example:

```
wsdl2java -t -or -Ejavaversion 1.5 -uon -uri ws.wsdl
```